# Chrome Extension Manifest Relative File Path for Scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have several utility script files that are used by multiple extensions. Thus far, I have been copy/pasting those utility scripts to each extension's root folder whenever I make a change. This is becoming less and less feasible. I would like to reference the same utility script files from both extensions' manifests. I have tried this:

```
{
    "background":
    {
        "scripts":
        [
            "../utils.js",
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

But, I when I reload my extension, I get an Extension error saying:

`Could not load extension from 'C:\...'. Could not load background script '../../utils.js'.`

If I use backslashes instead (this seems like a more likely solution since I'm working with windows...), I get the same error (but with backslashes).

Is it even possible to achieve this type of relative file path?

Comment: It seems like that would be an obvious security hole.  Perhaps you could have a batch file that would copy `utils.js` into the appropriate directories?

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a local server that hosts the JS files you need and then your extension can access those JS file through a localhost port and use their functionality? A simple lightweight server would do the trick (maybe [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) in Python).

Chrome v33 tightened up extension security so i'm not sure you can access a file like you tried in your manifest.json

Let me know how you get around this problem!

Comment: In python, you don't need to use a 3rd party library, just navigate to the folder you wish to serve files from and type run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [PortNumber]` on the command line :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Shared Modules](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/shared_modules)? According to the documentation you can export common functionality from one extension that can thusly be imported into another extension:

"The export field indicates an extension is a Shared Module that exports its resources:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "My Shared Module",
  "export": {
    // Optional list of extension IDs explicitly allowed to
    // import this Shared Module's resources.  If no whitelist
    // is given, all extensions are allowed to import it.
    "whitelist": [
      "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
    ]
  }
  // Note: no permissions are allowed in Shared Modules
}
```

The import field is used by extensions and apps to declare that they depend on the resources from particular Shared Modules:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "My Importing Extension",
  ...
  "import": [
    {"id": "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"},
    {"id": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
     "minimum_version": "0.5" // optional
    },
  ]
}
```

"

Comment: Link only answers are not helpful if the content changes or moves. Include the relevant parts of the link, and sample code, or provide it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: ok...I am not familiar enough with using that technique; I should have asked the question as a comment. my bad.